# If you're married, can you still file an income tax return as a single individual?

Tags: united-states, roth-ira, income-tax, marriage

Roth IRA limits on income make it advantageous for my wife to file single. We are getting married this year in November.

The IRS says that if you are married filing separately, that essentially she can't contribute to a Roth (unless she makes no money).

Are we able to each file single (not married separately, but single) even though we are married?

Comment: Welcome to an aspect of what some people call 'the marriage tax'

Comment: Consider yourselves lucky, there are other effects of the marriage issue. I have a rental property. With depreciation, etc, I had a paper loss each year. I got married and the loss will carry forward till I sell the property.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nope.

The IRS recognizes you as either [married or unmarried](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p17/ch02.html).